# Change class button on checkbox status true in datatable jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I work with data tables, and I have issues.

In table i have custom checkboxes, and i need to check status of box, for this i use this func:

```
 var table = $('#table').dataTable();
    var rowcollection = table.$(".subUsed:checked", { "page": "all" });

    rowcollection.each(function (index, elem) {
        var checkboxValue = $(elem).val();
        if (checkboxValue === true) {
            table.find(".addSubItem").removeClass('hide')
        } else {
            table.find(".addSubItem").addClass("hide")
        }
    });
```

It's check and in **checkboxValue** I get a result, I want to check if value **true** then in button which has class **.addSubItem** remove class hide.

But in some case, it's not removing.

Answer (score 0):

Was provide new code, maybe will help for somebody:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();
    table.rows().every(function () {
        if (this.nodes().to$().find(".input:checked").val()) {
            this.nodes().to$().find(".buttonClass").removeClass('hide')
        } 
    })
});
```